# Euler's proof of divergence of sum of reciprocals of primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, fake-proofs

On Wikipedia at [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes_diverges) currently is:

\begin{align}
 \ln \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\right) & {} = \ln\left( \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-1}}\right)
  = -\sum_p \ln \left( 1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \\
 & {} = \sum_p \left( \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{2p^2} + \frac{1}{3p^3} + \cdots \right) \\
 & {} = \left( \sum_{p}\frac{1}{p} \right) + \sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3p} + \frac{1}{4p^2} + \cdots \right) \\
 & {} < \left( \sum_p \frac{1}{p} \right) + \sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} + \cdots \right) \\
 & {} = \left( \sum_p \frac{1}{p} \right) + \left( \sum_p \frac{1}{p(p-1)} \right) \\
 & {} = \left( \sum_p \frac{1}{p} \right) + C
\end{align}

and since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, so must $\sum_{p} \frac{1}{p}.$

Currently there is language like "audacious leaps of logic" and "correct result by questionable means".

Wouldn't this be a valid proof if we reversed it, though? If we assume $\sum_p \frac{1}{p}$ converges, can't we just go through the steps backwards and find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ converges, contradiction? Euler's work seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

$
\ln \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\right)$ has no meaning.
It is like you say $$\ln (\infty)=...$$
But $\ln x$ is defined on real numbers and not on "anything we understand".
But everyone understands that Euler "understood" that the method was correct.
This is why the proof is attributed to him.

Comment: You can assign $\infty$ to diverging increasing sequences in which case the manipulations stated above are valid